# Prestashop upgrade from 1.7.1.2 to new version

Tags: prestashop, upgrade

Can Someone tell me the proper process to upgrade Prestashop 1.7.1.2 to the new version? I have to upgrade my Prestashop version because the PHP version I was using was outdated, so I have upgraded my PHP version. After I upgraded my PHP version, my Prestashop 1.7.1.2 backend didn't open. Because this version of PrestaShop won't support the latest PHP version. I don't want to use outdated PHP version also because my hosting provider charges me a lot.

It would be great, I can upgrade my PrestaShop. So, I need a proper step by step process to upgrade Prestashop.

Also, how do I change my shop into maintenance mode by changing the code? Keep in mind, my backend won't open. I have to change it programmatically.

I already have done a lot of google searches and won't get the proper procedures.

Comment: You can use the 1-click upgrade module which comes with prestashop. (https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/keeping-up-to-date/upgrade/#1-click-upgrade-module)

Comment: I tried that one too but it was not upgraded properly so I have to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

To disable your shop from the database, go to the configuration table and
search where name = PS_SHOP_ENABLE, set this to NULL.